# How to replace fontawesome icons

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, font-awesome

I need a five-star rating system for a PHP page I'm working on. I initially tried MooTools, but the page uses jQuery and they clash, so I am trying to get a jQuery rating system to work, but the icons do not appear.

I followed the instructions on the website. The website did say that I could use my own icons instead of font awesome icons, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Here is the JS file:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.stars = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
        stars: 5,
        emptyIcon: '&amp;#9734;',
        filledIcon: '&amp;#9733;',
        color: '#E4AD22',
        starClass: '',
        value: 0,
        text: null,
        click: function() {}
    }, options);
.
.
}
```

Here's the page where the stars should appear:

```
echo '<div id="stars" class="click-callback" style="height:34px;width:300px;border:1px solid red;margin: 5px auto;"></div>';
$('#stars').stars({
    click: function(i) {
       alert(i);
    }
});
```

I tried replacing (as you can see in the code) the font awesome icon with Unicode characters, but that doesn't work either. I am new at jQuery, so any help would be much appreciated.

I expect to see five-star outlines that fill in as the user mouses over them. Once the user clicks on a star, all the stars up to that point should be filled and the rating submitted.

Right now nothing appears where the stars are supposed to be.

Comment: I'm assuming that emptyIcon: and filledIcon: when using the font awesome icons refer to names in the font awesome .css file... so to use you own one would add their own custom.css , add the logic in there for the icons and then refer to them from emptyIcon and filledIcon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it, using css pseudo elements.

In the `mouseover` function, we add the class `.star-over` to that element's icon and all `.prevAll()` sibling's icons. Then in the `mouseleave` function we remove those classes.

On click, if the element does not have the `.rate-active` class, we will add `.rate-active` to it and add `.far` (solid star) to this element and previous element's icons. We also remove `.rate-active` from any previous siblings.

Here is a link to my codepen: https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/QXmgrV

```js
$(document).on({
  mouseover: function(event) {
    var star = $(this).find('.star');
    $(this).find('.far').addClass('star-over');
    $(this).prevAll().find('.far').addClass('star-over');
  },
  mouseleave: function(event) {
    var star = $(this).find('.star');
    $(this).find('.far').removeClass('star-over');
    $(this).prevAll().find('.far').removeClass('star-over');
  }
}, '.rate');


$(document).on('click', '.rate', function() {
  var star = $(this).find('.star');
  if (!$(this).hasClass('rate-active')) {
    $(this).siblings().find('.star').addClass('far').removeClass('fas rate-active').css('color', '#91a6ff');
    star.addClass('rate-active fas').removeClass('far star-over');
    $(this).prevAll().find('.star').addClass('fas').removeClass('far star-over').css('color', '#91a6ff');
  }
});
```

```css
.stars {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}

.star {
  color: #91a6ff !important;
}

.rate {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rate input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.star-over::after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  content: "\f005";
  display: inline-block;
  color: #d3dcff;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css">
<div class="stars">
  <label class="rate">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="star1" value="star1">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <i class="far fa-star star one-star"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="rate">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="star2" value="star2">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <i class="far fa-star star two-star"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="rate">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="star3" value="star3">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <i class="far fa-star star three-star"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="rate">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="star4" value="star4">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <i class="far fa-star star four-star"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="rate">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="star5" value="star5">
    <div class="face"></div>
    <i class="far fa-star star five-star"></i>
  </label>
</div>
```